# Web driver brower heap analysis

Tags: memory, browser, webdriver, heap-memory, dump

We are running our integration tests using selenium web driver(chrome/ie/firefox).

Is there are any options to analyze browser memory usage (heap analysis) from web driver tests.
(or)
 How can I integrate this with my integration tests.

Is there options to save browser heap snapshot while running the web driver test.

Please suggest.

Comment: To get browser screenshot during that , you can use any screen capture software.

Comment: @HelpingHands: I require browser memory usage snapshot like chrome dev tools js heap memory usage information

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helped, but I just ran my tests locally and looked at the system usage on my computer.

Its not exact, but it gave me a ball park 512M in use per thread.

Basically, I added up the Chrome jobs and the chromedriver job and I just used the heaviest Java job.

If you have found a better way please share :)